# Some sql commands and stored procedures work in SSMS, but not from a Python call

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc, create-table

I'm invoking SQL commands as well as stored procedures from python.  Some of the commands work well. In fact, I've done this kind of thing dozens of times with no problem.
Here's an example of some working code in the same file where I have the problem:

```
cursor.execute(r'select top 10 * from xyz')

for result in cursor.fetchall():
    last_predecessor = result[0]
    last_successor = result[1]
    print(last_predecessor, last_successor)
```

This works great!

I have this stored procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE make_new_table
AS
BEGIN

    drop table if exists abc
    
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    CREATE TABLE abc(
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ida_last_update_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [ida_last_update_source_file] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ID_RSSD_PREDECESSOR] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ID_RSSD_SUCCESSOR] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [D_DT_TRANS] [date] NULL,
    [TRNSFM_CD] [int] NULL,
    [ACCT_METHOD] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [DT_TRANS] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

END
```

I can invoke this from the ssms query window with

```
exec make_new_table
```

Also works fine.

But when I try to execute this from python with:

```
cursor.execute("exec make_new_table ")
```

It fails. (Tried it with and without the trailing space) No error!  It just doesn't do anything.

I also tried to invoke:

```
cursor.execute('drop table if exists xyz ')
```

This also fails - doesn't drop the table, but produces no error (and it shouldn't).

So is there some limit to what can be done from pyodbc? Can we not drop and create tables?

Comment: "It fails" and similar statements are never useful things to post. When an error occurs, post the complete error message - all of it. My guess is that you are not careful about the values you use to populate your connection string and you assume too much when you write sql statements. If you need to add the database name to your sql statements to make them execute successfully, then does that not imply the current database of your connection is not what you assume?

Comment: I will try to be clearer next time. In each case where it "failed" [to do what it was supposed to do], it produced no error message.

Comment: Try moving the `drop table` statement below `SET NOCOUNT ON;`. It would be best if `SET NOCOUNT ON;` was the very first statement in the stored procedure.

Comment: Will do.  But I think I once again figured out something that works. autocommit=True when I init the connection.  I think I fixed it and then broke it when I was backtracking with git and getting frustrated.  But I'll definitely move that after the SET NOCOUNT ON.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution:
The real solution was a change in my init_connection() function which I did not include in my OP.  The only change necessary was to make **autocommit=True** . No need to specify the database in the stored procedure or the call.  When I had the previous solution that was inconsistent I had stupidly made two changes and only focused on the one that did not really fix it.  It was setting the autocommit that fixed it.

```
def init_connection(server_name, db_name):
    """
    Connect to SQL Server database
    :param server_name:
    :param db_name:
    :return:
    """
    pyodbc.pooling = False
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
            r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server_name + '; \
            Database=' + db_name + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;', timeout=5, autocommit=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to connect to database [" + db_name + '] and server [' + server_name + ']')
        print(e)
        exit(1)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return [conn, cursor]
```

I removed my previous (non-working) solution.

Comment: When your Python code was running the default schema wasn't what you thought it was. If you have your Python app display the result returned by `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()` and then check that schema you'll probably find the table there.

Comment: I'll check that.